# .env file not in Heroku CI/CD with Gitlab

Tags: node.js, heroku, gitlab, environment-variables, dotenv

I am trying to deploy a Node.js application to Heroku via a GitLab pipeline. The below is my pipeline code. I have the variables set in the GitLab project. It seems as though the `.env` file is not uploaded to the Heroku app and the app crashes.

```js
image: node:latest

before_script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
   # - npm link @angular/cli

stages:
  #  - test
    - production


# unit-test:
   # stage: test
   # image: trion/ng-cli-karma:latest
   # script:
     #   - npm install 
    #    - ng test 
  #  only:
 #       - master

production:
    type: deploy
    stage: production
    image: ruby:latest
    script:
        - echo "ACCOUNT_SID=$ACCOUNT_SID" >> .env
        - echo "AUTH_TOKEN=$AUTH_TOKEN" >> .env
        - echo "API_KEY=$API_KEY" >> .env
        - echo "API_SECRET=$API_SECRET" >> .env
        - echo "PHONE_NUMBER=$PHONE_NUMBER" >> .env
        - echo "sengrid_api=$sengrid_api" >> .env
        - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY --skip_cleanup
    only:
        - master
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With this .yml file I am able to build my docker image and deploy to both of my Digital Ocean droplets at once with a load balancer in front of them.

```js
# ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> authorized_keys: use this command to add gitlab ssh keys to sever. Run on server terminal
# cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys : Run this command on the sever on the terminal. 
# Both COMMANDS ABOVE ARE necessary.
# Have to put .env echo statments in Docker build stage because documents dont persist. Artifacts could be used.

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA


build-App:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - echo   "ACCOUNT_SID=$ACCOUNT_SID" >> .env
    - echo   "AUTH_TOKEN=$AUTH_TOKEN" >> .env
    - echo   "API_KEY=$API_KEY" >> .env
    - echo   "API_SECRET=$API_SECRET" >> .env
    - echo   "PHONE_NUMBER=$PHONE_NUMBER" >> .env
    - echo   "sengrid_api=$sengrid_api" >> .env
    - cat .env
    - docker build . -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST 
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

deploy-1:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client git -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*.pub
  - ssh-add
  - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - ls -ld ~/.ssh/*
  script:
    - ssh   -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f my-app || true"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://134.122.23.185
  only:
    - master

deploy-2:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment-backup
  before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client git -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_BACKUP" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY_BACKUP" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*.pub
  - ssh-add
  - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - ls -ld ~/.ssh/*
  script:
    - ssh   -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER_BACKUP@$SERVER_IP_BACKUP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER_BACKUP@$SERVER_IP_BACKUP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER_BACKUP@$SERVER_IP_BACKUP "docker container rm -f my-app || true"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER_BACKUP@$SERVER_IP_BACKUP "docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment:
    name: production-backup
    url: http://161.35.123.72
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 3):

> It seems as though the `.env` file is not uploaded to the Heroku app

Nor should it be.

`.env` files are a convenient mechanism for setting environment variables *in development*. On Heroku, you should use [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), which are *its* convenient mechanism for setting environment variables, e.g.

```
heroku config:set API_KEY=SOME_API_KEY
```

Note that you may need to quote values if they contain characters like `<` or `|` which are meaningful to whatever shell you are using.

If you need these variables at build time, you can [set environment variables as part of your GitLab configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-environment-variables) (committed to your repository) or [in group-level secrets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#group-level-environment-variables) (not committed, and in some ways more aligned with the concept of per-environment settings).

Each *environment* in which you run your application is different and should have its own environment variables. It is normal and expected that they don't follow your application around. This is [one of the fundamental principles](https://12factor.net/config) upon which Heroku's model was designed.

Comment: hmmm ok. I have the variables defined in Gitlab for the pipeline, but my app needs these variables to run. Could you explain more definitely on how I could pass these variables to my app?

Comment: @augdog97, as config vars (see link in my answer). I usually use the command line, e.g. `heroku config:set FOO=bar`, but there is also an interface for doing this in the web dashboard, too.

Comment: Alright I appreciate it, I set the vars and it did not work. I am still working on a solution.

Comment: @augdog97, I'm sorry to hear that. What does "it did not work" mean, specifically?

Comment: I added the vars, but the app still did not use the vars. Please the above edited .yml file. I got the .env file to be created, but the variables still are not being used.  Nano doesn't work with the Heroku CLI so I cant see in the .env file. Shoul I try to add the config vars now that the .env file is created?

Comment: You should _not be using a `.env` file on Heroku at all_, and you _cannot_ expect to modify a file once it has been deployed due to Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). All files that are part of your app must be included in your application slug at build time. For environment variables, _use Heroku's config vars_. "but the app still did not use the vars"—this is what you should be digging into. "Please the above edited .yml file"—the GitLab CI configuration file is irrelevant at runtime.

Comment: @augdog97, can you edit your question and show how you're trying to use the environment variables in your application code?

Comment: I actually solved this issue last night. I am formulating the answer right now. I ended up having to put the echo statements before the docker build script steps